# npm custom typescript package - types show as any

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I've created a private npm library with typescript and I'm trying to consume it from a React app (that does *not* use typescript).

Here is the `tsconfig.json` of the library:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES2017",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "lib": ["es2017", "es7", "es6", "dom"],
    "declaration": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "strict": true,
    "baseUrl": "./src",
    "outDir": "./lib",
    "rootDir": "./src",
    "paths": {
      "src/*": ["./src/*"]
    },
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

The folder structure is the following:

```
package
   /src
      index.ts
      /types
         FuncTypes.ts
      /utils
         someFunc.ts
```

The `FuncTypes.ts` file:

```
export interface FuncOptions {
  value: string;
}
```

The `someFunc.js` file:

```
import { FuncOptions } from "types";

export default (options: FuncOptions ): void => {
  console.log(options);
};
```

And finally, the `index.ts`:

```
import { default as someFunc } from "./utils/someFunc";

export { someFunc };
```

I publish it successfully, install it successfully from the React app but whenever I use `someFunc()` the type of `options` shows as `any`.

I believe the issue is with the absolute paths and how I've configured them.

Any ideas?

Comment: I am not sure but it might happen cause you did not provide these options
declarationDir
declarationMap

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.

After running `tsc`, the paths in the `outDir` (`lib`) were still relative to the `src` folder.

I had to install [`tscpaths`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tscpaths) and change the build command to `"build": "tsc --project tsconfig.json && tscpaths -p tsconfig.json -s ./src -o ./lib"`.